# Blocking read function in c in a client/server application

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, client-server

I'm currently developing a client/server architecture between a tablet (client) and a MAC/PC (server). I am doing on both side some real-time rendering and I need communication between the two.

The problem is that I need to do some operation on the string I get from my client (which is basically a rotation matrix). This string is therefore to be at most 16 float numbers that I previously transform into a coma-separated-value string.
Therefore what I should get from my client is something like:

> 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0

Server-side, I do some processing of that string to get back my rotation matrix as a float array of 16 elements. The problem is that sometimes I get more than just 16 elements from the client on the server side at once. I for instance get

> 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
>   1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
>   1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0

So that when I try to split it, I go above the 16 element limits which is not good at all for me.
My question is: is there a way to prevent the server and/or the client to read/send more than one complete matrix at a time? Since I'm using a tablet and some real-time rendering I would like to be able to save as much processing power as possible.

Here is the code that I'm using (just snippets as files are quite big)

Client:

```
if (connected == true && matrixupdated == true && this.hasMatrixChanged()){
            try {
                this.inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                this.outToServer= new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                this.sentence = this.getStringFromMatrix();
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
                this.hasServerProcessed = false ;
                System.arraycopy(matrix, 0, previousMatrix, 0, 16); //I check whether the matrix changes enough for me to send it to the server
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
            }
            this.matrixupdated = false ;
```

Server :

```
while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
{
    smatrix = client_message ;  //smatrix is a true c++ string
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&mycondition, &mymutex); // prevent real-time rendering to try and use the matrix at the same time as this function
    std::stringstream ss(smatrix);
    while(std::getline(ss, tok, ',')) {
        matrix[i] = ::atof(tok.c_str());
        i++ ;
    }
    i = 0 ;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
}
```

Comment: If you got them in lines ( 16 per line) you can use the new line to distinghuish the ... lines.

Comment: That's exactly what I did but I wondered whether there was a more efficient and clean way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working as designed. TCP is a byte stream protocol. There are no message boundaries. If you want messages you have to implement them yourself.

Comment: In my experience the easiest way to do that in Java is to use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream and serialize/deserialize objects.